# How to offline my Node dependencies to deploy to Artifactory?

Tags: reactjs, npm, artifactory, yarnpkg

I have an Artifactory server that is not connected to the internet and can't be.  I have a React project that I need to be able to build using said Artifactory server.  How can I download/pack/tar all of my project dependencies and deploy them to Artifactory?

Answer (score 1):

you must have an internet connection to retrieve the node modules dependencies. once done, you can list all packages and their resolved url

```sh
find node_modules \
  -type f \
  -name package.json \
  -exec jq -r '._resolved' {} \; \
  | sort \
  | uniq
```

then download each of which and upload it to artifactory

Comment: Will this show all dependencies and their dependencies?  If so this could work, I could write a script to grab them all.

Comment: I ended up just adding an npm proxy repo to my Artifactory, now the problem is I have packages with dependencies that reference Github, and Artifactory won't proxy those requests.