# Is it possible to archive node_modules of the project and then upload it to Nexus Repository Manager?

Tags: npm, registry, nexus

Closed network project needs a solution for packages. Is it possible to upload all modules from "node_modules" at once to Nexus Repository Manager ?

If it's possible how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

assuming [`npm` in configured to use nexus private repository](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/npm-registry#npmRegistry-PrivatenpmRegistries), once you have each node modules\package downloaded (usually through  `npm install`), you can use [`npm-publish`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-publish) and upload them to a private registry.

you might find the [following handy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62930795):

```sh
find node_modules \
  -type f \
  -name package.json \
  -exec jq -r '._resolved' {} \; \
  | sort \
  | uniq
```